# Why isn't permission to access a user's geolocation being asked in browser?

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation, navigator

I'm creating a simple weather scraper however am unable to get the browser to request permission to access a user's location.

JS is:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;

// onload event listener for api:
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let lon;
    let lat;
    // asks permission to access users location:
    navigator.permissions.request({ name: 'geolocation' })
        .then((permission) => {
            if (permission.state === 'granted'){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    try {
                        let lon = position.coords.longitude;
                        let lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        const locationData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={apiKey}`;


                        fetch(locationData).then((response) => {
                            return response.json();
                        })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error(error);
                            });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I had previously tried geolocation.getCurrentPosition (as below) but again this didnt work:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;

// onload event listener for api:
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let long;
    let lat;
    // accesses location of user:
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            const locationData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_key}`;

            fetch(locationData).then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            });
        }
)}
});
```

I've tried the below but still no luck:

```
* Re-opened live server in Safari but Safari doesnt ask for permission to access location either.
* Confirmed Chrome & Safari had permission to access my location on my Mac.
* Realised I hadn't correctly used string interpolation for the locationData URL; so corrected URL.
* Code wrapped in try-catch.
* Created new API key.
* Added "navigator.permissions.request" but still no luck
```

The only errors in console are:

main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at main.js:1:1

and then in terminal in VS code:

window.addEventListener('load', () => { ^ ReferenceError: window is not defined.

The errors have remained regardless of whether I use the Permission  API or not.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's development console?  In the browser's script debugger, when you place breakpoints in this code, is this code and any of the callback functions executed at all?

Comment: The only error in console is:

main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main.js:1:1


and if I run the code in VS code I get an error in terminal of:

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 1):

A lot of functionalities of [Permisions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions) are currently not supported by browsers.
I'd suggest taking a look at [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) instead.

Looking at your comment below, I think this should work for you though:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    const lon = position.coords.longitude;
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const locationData = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_key}`;
    fetch(locationData).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

About the reference error on `window.addEventListener` it's because you're currently running this code on server too. You shouldn't be doing this as `window` is only available in browser. You can prevent this from happening by simply adding a check:

```
// runs only on client
if(typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The thing is you cannot use `require()` unless you've got a bundler. Even if you have, you need to find a **secure** way of exposing your environment variable to your client without making it publicly visible.

Comment: In that case i'll just comment it out for the time being and forget about hiding my API Key :) thank you - it's working now.

Comment: No worries! Please also mark it as the correct answer if you think it was.

Comment: I've already done so but I need a reputation of 15 for it to show (currently 11). It says my feedback has been recorded so hopefully will show when I reach 15. Thank you for your help again!